# Multiple scrollable divs, one function up/down buttons

Tags: jquery

I have multiple text div containers (same class: **.rocksZoom_textContainer**) which I control via up/down scroll buttons. These containers are never visible together - there's a show()/hide() between them.

The code for the buttons is as follows:

```
$('.rocksZoom_textBox_btnUp').on('mouseenter', function(){
  if ($('.rocksZoom_textContainer').scrollTop() === 0){ return; }
  // 
});

$('.rocksZoom_textBox_btnUp').on('mouseleave', function(){
  // 
});

$('.rocksZoom_textBox_btnUp').on('mousedown', function(){
  if ($('.rocksZoom_textContainer').scrollTop() === 0){ return; }
  // 
  function scroll_ContDn(){
    $('.rocksZoom_textContainer').stop().animate({scrollTop:'-=50'}, 500, 'linear', scroll_ContDn);
  } 
  scroll_ContDn();
});

$('.rocksZoom_textBox_btnUp').on('mouseup', function(){
  if ($('.rocksZoom_textContainer').scrollTop() === 0){ return; }
  // 
  function stopScroll_ContDn(){
    // Stuff animated
  }
  stopScroll_ContDn();
});
```

The jQuery code for the show()/hide():

```
function zoomContainer_showHide(){
  $(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer:visible").hide();
  $(".rocksMenu_zoomContainer").eq(menuItem_place).show();
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="rocksZoom_textContainer">
  <p>Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text...</p>
</div>
```

How can I reuse the buttons functions to work on all text containers independently?

Pedro

Comment: can you provide fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only 1 rocksZoom_textContainer will be visible at one time you could use the ":visible" selector:

```
$('.rocksZoom_textBox_btnUp').on('mouseenter', function(){
    if ($('.rocksZoom_textContainer:visible').scrollTop() === 0){ return; }
    // 
});
```

...and then the same principle for the remaining functions.

**Note** :visible is a pseudo selector so if you have a lot of these your performance might be better if you toggle a class or attribute to indicate which rocksZoom_textContainer is visible.

Then you just change your code to something like this:

```
$('.rocksZoom_textBox_btnUp').on('mouseenter', function(){
    if ($('.active_textContainer').scrollTop() === 0){ return; }
    // 
});
```

...if active_textContainer was the class you used to indicate the currently active/visible one.

Have a look at this post: [Performance of jquery visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696779/performance-of-jquery-visible)