# Using .fadeIn() sequentially

Tags: jquery

I've got a bunch of divs, default set to `display:none`, which I would like to fadeIn one by one after a delay of 500ms. Approach below works great, but is it the way it should be?
What happens if there is no more div with the value of `display:none`?

```
function myFadeIn() {
    $(".myItems:hidden:first").fadeIn(500, function(){ myFadeIn(); });
}

("#myButton").click(function(){
    myFadeIn();
});
```

Comment: If there are no hidden divs then nothing will happen based on that, so it should work as you expect.

Comment: That should work fine. If there aren't any elements selected, the `fadeIn()` won't run, and the recursion will stop.

Comment: Tangentially, you can just pass `myFadeIn` directly as the callback, instead of a function that closes over and invokes it. `$(".myItems:hidden:first").fadeIn(500, myFadeIn);`

Comment: "Approach below works great, but is it the way it should be?" If you want cleaner coding, that's a different story.  If it "works great" then what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Dom, working example here http://jsfiddle.net/4BqWV/

Answer (score 0):

I made a few little changes, in part to make your function more generic, but otherwise your code should work.

```
function recursiveFadeIn(selector) {
    $(selector+":hidden").eq(0).fadeIn(400, function(){ 
        recursiveFadeIn(selector); 
    });
}

$("#myButton").on("click",function(e){
    recursiveFadeIn("ul > li");
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qNABc/1/

I replaced the ":first" selector with eq(0) for performance (See
[jQuery :first vs. .first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first)), and there are many other little rtweaks that you can do if you're crazy about performance (see [Performance of jquery visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696779/performance-of-jquery-visible)).