# Slowing javaScript. Bug. jQuery.is(":visible")

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, memory-leaks

I have a piece of code, that is causing some sort of memory leak. After many hours of testing I've managed to track it down to `elem2.is(":visible");`.

How I tracked it down -> My code loops on itself after a 1 second delay. I set this delay to 0 and saved the average time taken to do 10 iterations. I ended up with a list of integers as shown below.

Here is my 'Speed test' without any memoryLeaks, etc:

```
"4128 , 3964 , 4054 , 3994 , 3946 , 4011 , 4117 , 4044 , 4036 , 3945 , 4031 , 3859 , 4015 , 4019"
```

I've only included the first view results. But you can see it takes an average of 4000ms to complete the loop ten times.

Next here are the values when I include `elem2.is(":visible");`

```
 5128 , 4967 , 4975 , 5085 , 5127 , 5261 , 5550 , 5804 , 6160 , 6395 , 6617 , 7056 , 7658 , 8191 , 8492 , 9038 , 9364 , 10242 , 10893
```

As you can see the time taken to do 'x' amount of loops increases exponentially.

Here is the code:

```
function foo() {
    var elem1 = $("#A"),
        elem2 = $("#B");

    if(elem1.length && elem2.length && elem2.is(":visible")) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of any know issues with this function? Anyway to avoid it slowing down my function? (I'd be most interested to find out WHY it does this too).

Thanks

Comment: Note: I've managed to remove the bug. Check using `elem2.css("hidden") !== "none"` instead. Still very curious why this bug occurs.

Comment: Note: I should mention this bug will only occur if you do something like `for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {foo();}`.

Comment: Note: In the end I used `elem[0].offsetHeight && elem[0].offsetWidth`. If either is '0' then elem is hidden. After doing this change my 'SpeedTest' gave steady/consistent results no matter how long I ran it for.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer on this page sums it up nicely
[Performance of jquery visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696779/performance-of-jquery-visible)

To quickly summarize.  When using the jquery :visible property, you are really checking more than one property.  In regards to your speed checks, it's possible the checks are adding up.  I'm sure these speeds will vary depending on browser.

Comment: Thanks. Reading through now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a memory leak. JavaScript isn't multithreaded and can only perform one function at a time, the problem is that the process of `elem2.is("visible")` is taking longer than 0 seconds before your next timeout/setinterval is fired so it is queued up therefore causing a cumulative effect on your times.

Comment: I only call the timeout/setinterval after foo(); is called. As javaScript isn't multithreaded (excluding workers) it would be impossible for the next loop through to be called before elem2.is("visible"); is called.

Comment: I'm afraid you would get a -1.